# Is it a race condition?

Tags: c++, race-condition

Two threads are executing a function named `job`, inside which they are incrementing a global variable. Will there be a race condition here?

```
int i = 0;

void *job(void *args)
{
    i += 1;
}
```

Comment: Unsynchronized access to a non-atomic object in multiple threads, with at least one a write, is always a _data race_ and undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this might result in parallel access to the variable, which is a problem. To avoid that, it's recommended to declare `i` as `std::atomic<int>`.